# Elmah is not logged actual method and cotroller name when Attribute Routing Implement in WebAPI

Tags: elmah

I have implement the Attribute Routing in my webAPI. I have also implement Elmah in my project. I use  ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(context.Exception); line to log the exception in Elmah. I am not able to see actual Action Name & Controller Name In SQL Server Error Table.

For Example:
My Attribute RouteName is V1\Emp\Salary

My Actual Controller Name: EmployeeInformation 
My Actual Method Name: SalaryDetail

So I am able to see EMP as Controller name and Salary as Action Name in SQL Error Table.

Please let me know how to solve this issue.